# Internet app calls intranet page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, intranet

This is not so much of a specific question, but more a general one. I'm redoing one of my old projects and to make it more user friendly I want the following:

The project will be running on my home server, with a flask/python backend. User using my website will be coming from my companies intranet. Would it be possible to load an intranet page in a iframe on my website.

So in short, is it possible to load an intranet page from an internet-page that has no access to said intranet.

Comment: An iframe can load any page that the client can load normally.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: yes, but what then? Same-origin policies apply so having the intranet page in an iframe won't mean that your wrapper can interact with it via javascript, say.

Comment: I can't use javascript to extract the htmldoc of said intranet page?

Comment: @Difusio: You requested to show the site in a iframe, not to access its contents. That's a completely different issue, and you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can load it in an iframe, you don't need access to the page from the internet for that - the *client* needs it. Yet, the intranet application might request not to be viewed in a frame.

Comment: And am I correct that I would need a client side language to do this? Or can I just as well initiate the request for the page from python?

Comment: You can set the src attribute on the <iframe> from python.

Comment: An iframe is just html markup in your page. There's no scripting needed, or what do you want to do?

Comment: I need to get the HTML doc from the intranetpage for further processing.

Comment: @Difusio: That's impossible, as it would violate the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (unless allowed explicitly by the intranet page via [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). You can only display it in your page, but not access its contents via a scripting language (and not via a proxy either, since it's intranet).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Any page that the user can browse to normally can be loaded in an iframe.